# pyside - auto scroll down in qscrollarea

Tags: python, pyside

how down the scroll when new data arrives? I want to go down with the new data, but the scroll is kept in the same place. how to lower scroll automatically?

I tried using:

```
maximumY = self.scroll.verticalScrollBar().maximum()
self.scroll.verticalScrollBar().setValue(maximumY)
```

but, not work

**SOLVED**

```
self.scroll.verticalScrollBar().rangeChanged.connect(self.ResizeScroll)
def ResizeScroll(self, min, maxi):
    self.scroll.verticalScrollBar().setValue(maxi)
```

Comment: How exactly does new data arrive?

Comment: the data coming from mysql. I implement them QVBoxLayout, later a QGroupBox and then make a self.scroll.setWidget(QGroupBox)

Comment: have you tried connecting the scroll bar's rangeChanged(min, max) Bsignal? Also note, that since the scrollbar will always force its value to be within the legal range, you should always be able to set it to a very large value and get the right result.

Comment: thanks, it worked rangeChanged :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be a succinct way to get the behaviour desired - please check.

```
bar = self.scroll.verticalScrollBar()
bar.rangeChanged.connect( lambda x,y: bar.setValue(y) )
```

or

```
bar.rangeChanged.connect( lambda x,y: bar.setValue( 9999 ) )
```